# Cannot index into a null array, but there is no array, it's a hash table, and the hash table isn't empty

Tags: powershell

I have the following code, which is a bit more than minimally functional, but I hope it's still understandable.

```
$data = 'PATH TO SOME FILE OR FOLDER'
$rule = @{
    property = 'size'
    operator = 'lt'
    value = '1000gb'
    note = $null
    logOnForgo = $false
}
$ruleOperationArguments = @{
    operator = $rule.operator
    operand1 = $Null # always the current state to be tested, and depends on specific rule
    logString1 = $rule.property
    operand2 = $rule.value
    logString2 = $rule.value # sometimes modified by rule
    note = $rule.note
    logOnForgo = $rule.logOnForgo
}

if (($item = Get-Item $data).PSIsContainer) {
    $actualSize = 0
    foreach ($childItem in (Get-ChildItem $item -recurse | Where {-not $_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName})) {
        $actualSize += (Get-Item $childItem).length
    }
} else {
    $actualSize = $item.length
}
$ruleOperationArguments.operand1 = $actualSize
if ($actualSize -gt 1TB) {
    $actualSizeString = "$([math]::Round(($actualSize/1TB),2))TB"
} elseif ($actualSize -gt 1GB) {
    $actualSizeString = "$([math]::Round(($actualSize/1GB),2))GB"
} elseif ($actualSize -gt 1mb) {
    $actualSizeString = "$([math]::Round(($actualSize/1MB),2))MB"
} elseif ($actualSize -gt 1kb) {
    $actualSizeString = "$([math]::Round(($actualSize/1KB),2))KB"
} else {
    $actualSizeString = "$([math]::Round(($actualSize),2))Bytes"
}
$ruleOperationArguments.logString1 = "$($ruleOperationArguments.logString1) ($actualSizeString)"

# test size
switch ($interval[0].Groups['unit'].Value) {
    kb {$ruleOperationArguments.operand2 = [System.Int64]($interval[0].Groups['number'].Value) * 1kb}
    mb {$ruleOperationArguments.operand2 = [System.Int64]($interval[0].Groups['number'].Value) * 1mb}
    gb {$ruleOperationArguments.operand2 = [System.Int64]($interval[0].Groups['number'].Value) * 1gb}
    tb {$ruleOperationArguments.operand2 = [System.Int64]($interval[0].Groups['number'].Value) * 1tb}
}

$ruleOperationArguments
```

I am getting a very odd error

> Cannot index into a null array. At line:39 char:41

that line is

```
$ruleOperationArguments.logString1 = "$($ruleOperationArguments.logString1) ($actualSizeString)"
```

But here is the odd thing. the code WORKS. The actual final value of `$ruleOperationArguments.logString1` IS updated to include the actual size data.

I have also tried not modifying the hash table value by appending to itself, instead using, same result.

```
$ruleOperationArguments.logString1 = "$($rule.property) ($actualSizeString)"
```

It's not actually related to the data being put into the hash table, because

```
$ruleOperationArguments.logString1 = "WTAF?"
```

also throws the error. What is different about the logStrings that causes problems, while the operands are working without issue? I even tried running the code in a new instance of the ISE, thinking I could have issues with persisting variables. Nope, same issue. I am utterly stumped. I should not that I got a lot fo hits searching on 'Cannot index into a null array' but they all reference actual situations where an array is empty. But `$ruleOperationArguments` sent to the console will show that the only part of the hash table that is empty is the note key that I am not even using, and operand1 that get's populated before the error condition. Both logStrings have values, and I can successfully update them, but this false error still gets thrown.

EDIT: To minimize the complexity I tried this

```
$rule = @{
    property = 'size'
    operator = 'lt'
    value = '1000gb'
    note = $null
    logOnForgo = $false
}
$ruleOperationArguments = @{
    operator = $rule.operator
    operand1 = $Null
    logString1 = $rule.property
    operand2 = $rule.value
    logString2 = $rule.value
}
$ruleOperationArguments
$ruleOperationArguments.logString1 = "$($ruleOperationArguments.logString1) changed"
$ruleOperationArguments
```

And thworks with no errors. So something is the rest fo the code is causing the issue, but I still have no clue what.

Comment: I tried this by cherry picking the relevant bits from your code (I had to provide a fake size) but same as with your condensed edit, I'm not getting an error

Comment: In your original code, can you throw a `Write-Warning $ruleOperationArguments.logString1` on the line immediately prior to the erroring line? Do you still get an error? If you get an error, does it still print the string "size"?

Comment: So, I tried a few other things and in fact the only thing I CAN modify is `$ruleOperationArguments.operand1`, which is `$null`. I thought operand2 was working, but I seem to have another issue there. But I still can't see where I do anything to break the variable.

Comment: I tried the warning, and it prints fine, with the correct initial value. And the very next line fails.

Comment: Try this for the write-warning string instead `"$($ruleOperationArguments.logString1)"`

Comment: Powershell 5.1, for what it's worth.

Comment: `"$($ruleOperationArguments.logString1)"` shows the initial value as expected. And using that string for `Write-Warning` also works fine.

Comment: Curriouser and curiouser. If I put `$ruleOperationArguments.logString1` to echo to the console right AFTER the erring line, the revised value is echoed to screen, but BEFORE the error. How is that even possible?

Comment: Wait.... are you 100% sure you didn't modify your original code block and the line count is accurate for the line in the error? I ran the very bottom part (I omitted before) and now I get the error but within the switch statement

Comment: That is happening because you don't have `$interval` defined as an array anywhere: `Cannot index into a null array.`, `+ switch ($interval[0].Groups['unit'].Value) {`

Comment: I am NOT 100% sure, but close. And I AM 100% sure the error specifically mentioned logString 1, while everything in the switch is related to operand2. That said, I just remmed the whole switch and I DO NOT get the error.

Comment: Hmm, that is true, but odd that the error being reported had nothing about Interval. But that gives me a thread to follow. In the morning perhaps, it's been a LONG day.

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere, you swizzled the line mentioned in the error. When I run the original sample locally, up to the line mentioned in the error and question, the error doesn't occur, and there is nothing that should cause this above. However, running the whole thing results in the same error... but for the `switch` statement condition. Ignore the line number mismatch here:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:9
+ switch ($interval[0].Groups['unit'].Value) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Looking more closely at this, `$interval` isn't defined anywhere. You need to initialize this as an `Array`, `List`, or some other type of collection.